# Facebook native app Login Issue in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed an application which have facebook login issue with native application. If native app is not install then app facebook login working fine. but if native app is install then app is working only for single facebook id by which i create application id. For others facebook ids app not working.

Please help me how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: i think you are using a permission that you need to get approved from facebook by submitting your app.

Comment: I am taking only basic data of the user. So, why should i need permission from the Facebook?

Comment: what is the behavior you expect? Are you expecting the app to allow for any user with a Facebook ID to access it, regardless of which user is logged into the Facebook app?

Comment: Yes. I want that to access my app by all user.

Comment: Is your app live? what do you mean by "`not working`"? this is really not that helpful